# CODE HELP on rounding down and producing correct input

Tags: c++, c

Question:

> Your task is to:
>
> Write a function that prints to the standard output (stdout) the number of users who didn't leave the site after 10 seconds (i.e: the number of users who didn't bounce).
>
> Please round the result downwards to the nearest integer (e.g both `7.1` and `7.9` are rounded to `7`).
>
> Note that your function will receive the following arguments:
>
> `n` which is an integer representing the number of visitors
>
> `b` which is an integer representing the bounce rate (i.e: the percentage of users who left the site in the first 10 seconds)

My code compiles just fine and I am pretty sure that my logic is correct, but my output is wrong and I don't know why. When `n = 1000` and `b = 25` then my result should be `750`. I keep on getting `1000`. Where am I going wrong?

I am also not exactly sure how to "round down" the way that they want me to. Could that also be the reason why I am not getting the correct output?

MY CODE:

```
void compute_active_users(int n, int b) {

    int BounceConvert = (b / 100); //converts the value of b to a decimal
    int BounceRate = (n * BounceConvert); // multiplys n times the b decimal
    int TotalVisitors = (n - BounceRate); // subtract BounceRate  

    printf("%d", TotalVisitors); // print out the final result

}
```

Comment: Integer division problems, perhaps?

Comment: Every integer division rounds down. You are just doing it too early.

Comment: `n * (100 - b) / 100`?

Comment: "_converts the value of b to a decimal_" apart from the fact that it doesn't convert anything at all, a `decimal` type is generally not the same thing as a `floating point` in most languages, and you should avoid mixing up the two terms.

Answer (score 1):

This uses the truncating behaviour of integer division in C for positive integers, which is the goal of your exercise:

```
void compute_active_users(int nbPeople, int bounceRate) {
    int totalVisitors = nbPeople * (100 - bounceRate) / 100;  
    printf("%d\n", totalVisitors);
}
```

Your solution does not work because this line:

```
int BounceConvert = (b / 100);
```

will produce `BounceConvert=0` (25/100 -> 0)

Answer (score 0):

Consider `b/100`. In Integer division, when b=25, it boils down to **0**, not 0.25 as  you expect. For that use floating point operation.

```
void compute_active_users(int n, int b) {
     float BounceRate = ((float)n * b)/100; // floating point operation
     int roundedBounceRate = (int) BounceRate; //Integer cast rounds it lowest integer
     int TotalVisitors = (n - roundedBounceRate); // subtract BounceRate  

     printf("%d", TotalVisitors); // print out the final result
}
```

Comment: But you don't *need* floating point numbers. At all!

Comment: so why does it boil down to "0" in division and why is "n" attached to the float in parenthesis when it is "b" that needs to be a float? Or are you storing that whole value at a float? :)